# how to create a nature shape in matlab?

Tags: matlab

i am a newbie here.. please excuse me for asking a straight forward question as i did not have the right information to do so.

for my question above, can anyone help me to create various shape in matlab?

i know how to make a simple triangle, rectangle in matlab.

what i am looking for is how to create animal patterns in matlab. all i need is the boundary layer (outer layer).
like from a bird / butterfly. something like the picture below.

butterfly wing:

[image: butterfly wing]

can anyone give me tips / links to help me.

and yes, i also did not have the coding. i am totally lost on how to make the pattern in matlab.

my real purpose was to add mesh pattern into the wings. i have the code for the mesh. all i need is the code on how to make the wing shape.

Comment: Two options....1. You must be having the coordinates in hand of the shape you want. 2. You should look whether any equation fits to the pattern you want.

Comment: MATLAB is a great programming tool, bud not as great to create art. Either you define mathemathically what you want, or open paint and draw some patters!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the image created by another program, you can import it to matlab using [`imread`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html). If you then want to get a binary boundary, you can use [`im2bw`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html).

```
threshold = 0.7; % you can play with this to get what you want
binary_img = im2bw(imread('PATH\TO\IMAGE.jpg'), threshold);
```

In matlab versions starting at `2016a` there is another function called [`imbinarize`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imbinarize.html) you might want to have a look at.

As for creating patterns from scratch, as already mentioned in the comments, matlab should not be your choice. Unless, of course, you have a well defined mathematical equation or a problem solution to which becomes the boundary. For this you can look into [`fimplicit`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fimplicit.html), [`fplot`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fplot.html) etc..